# Silverstripe custom security check show custom error message

Tags: security, authentication, silverstripe

I try to create a custom validate function to add to $LoginForm.

1- All members in group "Client" must be validated before they can login.

2- They will be redirected to the $LoginForm and show a custom message if account is not validated.

Is it possible to do that or must I program a new login form? If possible what is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: you mean validated like an email is sent with a link they have to click?

Comment: Yes, ive made à custom register form and send email validation... But how validate this through $LoginForm

Comment: It may be worth checking out the [SilverStripe member profiles module](https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-memberprofiles), which has this functionality in built.

Comment: True, my anwser come from this module. They are so many things in this module that I dont need. So I have made for my own usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. I have to extend DataExtension to Member object with :

```
public function canLogIn($result) {

        if(!$this->owner->Validation) {
            $result->error('You must validate your account before you can log in.');
        }
    }
```

And it work.

Comment: Extend is always ambiguous, you mean with a (Data)Extension class you "plug" to the Member Object? Not subclassing i guess...

Comment: I have extend DataExtension to the Member Object